# Switch user in a window on a Mac

Tags: macos, user-switching

Using MacOS X 10.6, is there a way to "switch users" in a window?  I'm looking for something like xnest.

Comment: Could you explain for what you need this? Maybe there are alternatives to running another user on the same system in a window.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can run single applications as another user using `sudo -u shortname /path/to/Application.app/Contents/MacOS/binaryname` (note that it requires the executable, not the application bundle! `open` fails to start applications as a different user).

A GUI way to do this might be [Pseudo](http://personalpages.tds.net/~brian_hill/pseudo.html), but I haven't tested it since a few years ago

Comment: To open an application from the terminal without digging around inside the bundle for the binary, use the open command i.e. sudo -u shortname open /path/to/Application.app

Comment: @Scott: Try it. It will fail, as I wrote in my answer. You *really* need to launch the binary directly, which is always in `Contents/MacOS/` and most of the time the only file there. So `C`, `[tab]`, `M`, `[tab]`, `[tab]` will get you there 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Fast User Switching](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8672.html) to run an application as another user with that user's preferences and data.